# Pushing UINavigationController into UIViewController Using Storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

My app's storyboard is using UIViewController's to go to different views of the app. However, I want to try a third party library, that is EGOPhotoViewer, not to reinvent the wheel. But how do I add UINavigationController to UIViewController from the storyboard? Here is the code this library is using to initialize.

```
EGOPhotoViewController *photoController = [[EGOPhotoViewController alloc] initWithPhotoSource:source];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:photoController animated:YES]
```

It only works for me when I add it as a view controller:

```
[self presentModalViewController:photoController animated:YES];
```

but the library works best within navigation controller because title bars and navigation buttons are missing from my testing approach.

Comment: Why do you want storyboard. This approach is more straightforward.

Comment: I do not want to rewrite library which works with nav controllers. I would use any best approach that works with my storeyboarded app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the storyboard

- select your original viewController, then in the menu:
- Editor -> embed in -> Navigation Controller  (that viewController becomes the rootViewController)

Now you have various options to push your photoController eg:

- From a UI widget in your rootViewController, CTRL-drag to photoController. That will create a segue which should work without extra code (although it helps to name the segue so that you can refer to it later in code)
- or in code as you have in the question.